# jQuery Sortable - How to get current dragged element attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jqueryui sortable widget. I need to get the current dragged element's data attribues. $(this).data('attribute_name') is not working here. I have also tried some other methods, but not getting the correct result.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="draggable-item" style="min-height:10px;">
   <li data-parent="31" data-id="81" class="ui-state-default">Label</li>
   <li data-parent="31" data-id="86" class="ui-state-default">Max Value</li>
   <li data-parent="31" data-id="83" class="ui-state-default">Unit</li>
   <li data-parent="31" data-id="84" class="ui-state-default">Warning Level High</li>
   <li data-parent="31" data-id="85" class="ui-state-default">Warning Level Low</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".draggable-item").sortable({
    start: function( event, ui ) { 
      //Here i need to get current dragged element's 'parent' attribue.
      //console.log(ui.item[0].attributes); - Here i got the entire attribute values in an array. But the order of the array is different in browsers.
    },
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `$(ui.item).data('attribute_name');` or `$(event.currentTarget).data('attribute_name');`

Answer (score 4):

Using `$(this)` will give you the element on which the sortable is initialized.  Refer the [Sortable Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable) . The current sortable item is stored in `ui` object and you can access it using `ui.item` .

So you can access any attribute of current sortable item by applying functions or methods on `ui.item` . Prefer using `$(ui.item)` .

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/173/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".draggable-item").sortable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            var attr = $(ui.item).attr('data-parent');
        },
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using at UPDATE event:

```
 update: function (event, ui) {

          var attr_id = ui.item.attr('data-id');
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly without problems.